# apache shiro concurrent user login

Tags: java, multithreading, shiro

Good afternoon!

I am working on a apache shiro project to set up a login system. I am able to setup a login platform based on google oauth security. Anyways my application right now allows one user to login successfully. If I open another tab in browser and login with a different user, my logic gets messed up. The latest user gets logged in using `SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(token)`. But the user in the other tab gets logged out or just lost.

I have no experience of writing concurrent user access before. Can any body help me with how to do it?

As container I am using embedded jetty by the way with java.

I have also tried to build the subject in several ways,

```
currentUser = new WebSubject.Builder(servletRequest, servletResponse).buildSubject();
```

and `Subject subject = new Subject.Builder().buildSubject();`
and

```
Subject requestSubject = new Subject.Builder().sessionId(sessionId)
                        .buildSubject();
```

Nothing working so far to provide concurrency.

Comment: You are expecting multiple users to be logged in within single browser session? I doubt that this will work...Try different browser or incognito mode.

Comment: @rkosegi That works actually! One in main window and other user in the incognito are able to operate simultaneously. Is there nothing else to it? Does it mean I have highest level of concurrency already?

Comment: browser will send back session cookie which identifies you (your session). That's why you can't have multiple users logged in at same time within same browser session. When trying to use same browser for multiple session, later will overwrite previous one.